# Generating Wind Rose Diagram

Tags: .net, r, statistics

I have a project that calls for a Wind Rose diagram. Specifically, I am looking to plot wind speed and direction over time in a visual format.

The example on this page looks like a function in a statistical language R which is probably far above my ability to undertake for this project.

I'm looking for any discussions of this algorithm, though ultimately this is for a .NET project.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a number of packages with windrose functions:
[Editted after comment from @zx8754]

https://rdrr.io/cran/plotrix/man/oz.windrose.html

https://rdrr.io/cran/oce/man/as.windrose.html

https://rdrr.io/cran/openair/man/windRose.html

https://rdrr.io/cran/climatol/man/rosavent.html

https://rdrr.io/cran/plotrix/man/oz.windrose.html

Comment: Thanks. From my research as well it looks like if you want a windrose, R is the language to use.

Comment: Links are broken, maybe update with "rdrr.io" https://rdrr.io/cran/plotrix/man/oz.windrose.html ?

Comment: Maybe someone will write a script that searches for all the dead links to the upenn server that served the R community for so many years. I used the link in the earlier comment to replace the stem and `/html/` in each of those links and they now all work.